# Why app is not crashing on 6.0 (API23) platform for deprecated getResources().getColor() without support library?

Tags: android, deprecated

I decided to check what will happen if to run the app for deprecated method excluding support library. I expected it have to crash. I use deprecated `getResources().getColor()` method for my device's Android 6.0 (API23) platform.
    Why doesn't it crash? (It's like support library in later platforms to support earlier ones)

```
MainActivity.java:    

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "scanandbuy.com"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't it crash?

Why would it?

"Deprecated" does not mean "will crash". "Deprecated" means "there is a replacement that we would like you to strongly consider using, on the API levels where the replacement exists".

Occasionally, a deprecated method will also have behavior changes. Usually, that is for privacy or security reasons, and usually, the changed behavior is not a crash but rather something more benign (e.g., returning an empty result set rather than the results you would have gotten before). Retrieving a color resource value does not have any privacy or security concerns that I can think of.

Comment: Thanks, Mark for the answer. Accepted!) 
I just discussing into myself about Android OS internal work like: Android 6.0 will find not existing in API23 method and that's why it will crash :) And the next my thought is that OS system has no any API and it just implements 0 and 1 executing code of app. So in IDE I made app which as well contains 0 and 1 executing code of deprecated method and OS doesn't care if it deprecated or not)

Comment: Mark, what could be exapmple "for privacy or security reasons"? Thanks!

Comment: @KirylIvanou: There are some deprecated methods on `ActivityManager` that now return altered results.

Comment: Why there is no compile error when i set in build.gradle minSdkVersion 23 and use deprecated method in activity, say, getResources().getColor(). I expected that it has to be compile error because there is no such method in API23. How it work, why it compiles successfully anyway?

Comment: @KirylIvanou: Java deprecation does not result in compile errors. `javac` will give you a warning, and usually IDEs will as well (e.g., Android Studio does). "I expected that it has to be compile error because there is no such method in API23" -- there most certainly is a one-parameter `getColor()` method on `Resources` in API Level 23. And API Level 24, API Level 25, and Android O. And probably for all future versions of Android, for backwards-compatibility reasons. You can read [the JavaDocs for it](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int)).